# Hibernate DiscriminatorColumn.Type not working

Tags: java, hibernate, discriminator

I have an abstract class AbstractTile

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TILES")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "t_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "abstractTile")
public class AbstractTile {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;
//and so on
}
```

and many classes which inherited from AbstractTile

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "dirt")
public class DirtTile extends AbstractTile{
//some code
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "grass")
public class GrassTile extends AbstractTile{
//some code
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "water")
public class WaterTile extends AbstractTile{
//some code
}
```

problem is when I want to save them into database, it has error

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    TILES
    (/*some data*/, t_type) 
values
    (/*some data*/, 'dirt') 

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Wrong value for type int : dirt
```

What am I doing wrong?
The DiscriminatorType is set to String so why it wants int?

EDIT: SQL create statement

```
CREATE TABLE tiles
(
  t_type character varying(31) NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  isaccesible boolean,
  x integer NOT NULL,
  y integer NOT NULL,
  map_id integer NOT NULL,
  building_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT tiles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk4c20b65b1a758e7 FOREIGN KEY (building_id)
      REFERENCES physical_building (building_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk4c20b65bd903ec4 FOREIGN KEY (map_id)
      REFERENCES map (map_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tiles
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code above with a t_type column of type VARCHAR, it worked fine. Is the t_type column in your database VARCHAR typed?

Comment: Its wierd but I dont have column t_type in my DB. Iam using PostgreSQL and the column is character varying typed. The abstract tile is mapped ManyToOne from some other classes can the problem be there?

Comment: It might help to post the create SQL for the TILES table. Also there is no need to have a DiscriminatorValue in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Hibernate bug running with postgres. I have no idea why it happnes, but if you change your table structure putting the discriminator column as the last field on your table it works!

In your case place the "t_type" after the "building_id" column.

I hope it helps!